# what dll we can use for windows phone 7 instead of system.runtime.remoting?

Tags: windows-phone-7, runtime, system

for windows phone 7

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http;
```

`system.runtime.remoting.dll` doesn't support for windows phone 7 platform. so please let me know what dll we can use for remoting confuration.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the Remoting technology is not supported on windows phone and there are no workarounds.

Windows Phone supports traditional networking (HTTP and sockets) as well as proximity APIs (Bluetooth, NFC, ...).

Especially, HTTP and sockets allow you call Web/WCF service & Web Api. That's all.